# One or more of your Android apps have a SHA-1 fingerprint and package name combination that's already in use

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

We had old Firebase project for application now we are using new Firebase project for same application. In old Firebase project there was one SHA key. Now I've removed that SSH key from old Firebase project and added in new Firebase project but at that time I'm getting this issue:

> One or more of your Android apps have a SHA-1 fingerprint and package name combination that's already in use

I want to use new Firebase project so how I can fix this issue and application is already live so I can't remove old Firebase?

I've removed SHA key from old Firebase project and added in new Firebase project but still getting this issue:

> One or more of your Android apps have a SHA-1 fingerprint and package name combination that's already in use

It been more than 6-7 days I've removed key from old project. I'm expecting that I can added SHA key in new Firebase project.

Comment: Login to you google cloud account and see if its still there . Api and services > Credentials.

Comment: This key should be in Firebase. How does that key come into the cloud account?

Comment: Firebase is part of google cloud.  A firebase project is also accessible via gcloud.

Answer (score 0):

same error occurred with me

I just go to the directory where my `.keystore` exists for my current project and delete this, then generate a new `.keystore`
`keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"`

Using this command for this project and then generate SHA-1 key now its unique and then use this SHA-1 key in my firebase